# Can I use Emoji as icon in navigation bar?

Tags: navigation

Emoji icons are 4byte UTF8 characters, the characters are not accepted in PDO, it would show errors like this question: [How can I remove emoji from all user input?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/121706/how-can-i-remove-emoji-from-all-user-input)

Instead, I used menu_icons plugin to prepend icons as picture before the navigation text, it uses picture background in CSS, but by using this method the text and picture will be overlapped.

If emoji is not an option, is there another way to prepend an icon before navigation text?

If emoji is an option, please help me bypass the PDO exception.

Thanks.

Comment: related: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/121706/how-can-i-remove-emoji-from-all-user-input Anyway, please clarify, I can't figure out what you are trying to do. Oh, and consider replacing / explaining *"emoji"* as *"4-byte UTF8 characters"*, not everyone knows that.

Comment: @Mołot I changed the backed-up sql file from utf8 to utf8mb4, imported to a new db. By setting the configuration file in Drupal's setting.php, drupal front page shows a lot of exceptions.

Comment: This solution also requires some configuration changes and one core hack, I'm afraid :( If you can't edit my.cnf or refuse to hack core, I can't help you. I hope someone else can provide another one, less invasive. Answer I posted is what I know and (once upon a time) tested.

Comment: @Molot when https://www.drupal.org/node/1926284 is official the `pdo` database key will take optional parameters allowing for `MySQL SSL` and other tweaks such as this (without hacking Core).

Comment: @tenken yes, indeed. Sadly, I don't think OP is willing to wait for [tag:8] and I don't think it'll be backported to [tag:7] any earlier.

Comment: @Mołot, I will try this method and report back here once I get anything out of it.

Comment: @Mołot, by the way I am using Drupal 7.

Comment: My answer was used on 7, too. But check the other one. It will, of course, leave you with errors if your apple-using clients will get creative, but it should do the job you asked here.

Answer (score 1):

Can't help with the PDO exception, but .. Have you looked at [IconAPI](https://www.drupal.org/project/icon) ? It has a sub module for use with menu items which doesn't cause overlapping as you described.

You can then use [Fontello](http://fontello.com/) as an icon provider and create a font set from the emoticons there, or import your own emoji icons into Fontello and download them as a font set.

Answer (score 0):

You can **switch my MySQL to utf8mb4 charset**, that supports all utf8 as it ought to be supported. You need MySQL 5.5.3 or greater to do this.

- make a backup (obvious, but hey)
- upgrade if needed
- for each database, table and column that has it set already, change to `CHARACTER SET = utf8mb4 COLLATE = utf8mb4_unicode_ci`
- Set `default-character-set = utf8mb4` for `[client]` and `[mysql]` in my.cnf
- Set (in the same file)

  ```
  [mysqld]
  character-set-server = utf8mb4
  collation-server = utf8mb4_unicode_ci
  ```
- Hack Drupal to use it. What you want is around line 53 of [/includes/database/mysql/database.inc](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!mysql!database.inc/7) - read comments there and replace "regular" UTF with the kind you need.

Hacking Drupal is usually not encouraged, but in this particular case we cannot expect a patch, so this is the only way to give users what they want. Also, it's method way less CPU consuming that altering all inputs.