# Webmail Error due to Emoji

Tags: webforms

A site I'm working on came across the following error in Drupal based on the addition of an emoji flex graphic put into the form field.

```
PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1366 Incorrect string value: ‘\xF0\x9F\x92\xAA e…’ for column ‘data’ at row 1: INSERT INTO {webform_submitted_data} (mid, sid, cid, no, data) VALUES (:db_insert_placeholder_0, :db_insert_placeholder_1, :db_insert_placeholder_2, :db_insert_placeholder3, :db_insert_placeholder_4); 
     Array ([:db_insert_placeholder_0] => 64
    [:db_insert_placeholder_1] => 10
    [:db_insert_placeholder_2] => 11
    [:db_insert_placeholder_3] => 0
    [:db_insert_placeholder_4] => Need multiple 250 ton Jacks, force not strong [AndroidFlexEmoji] enough) in drupal_write_record() (line 7239 of E:\webserver\Inetpub\wwwroot\includes\common.inc).
```

After digging around for a while on this site and others, I came across the following suggestion:

[mysqld]
character-set-server = utf8mb4
collation-server = utf8mb4_unicode_ci

I'm not 100% sure if this will fix the issue I'm having, however, I'm not sure where to alter this to test it. The link below states that in Drupal you can find it under /includes/database/mysql/database.inc around line 53 but no luck.

Reference link: [How can I remove emoji from all user input?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/121706/how-can-i-remove-emoji-from-all-user-input)
Any clarification would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the other issues weren't able to resolve the issue, I was able to work around the problem by installing a module called, [WebForm Validation](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_validation) to correct the issue. The way I did this was by creating a validation rule that was part of a "blacklist" of content that would be unacceptable in the form, then checked the box to reverse the rule so that it would be negated should the form contain anything not found in that previously created list. This list contained all my standard alphanumeric needs and punctuation. Not the ideal fix, however, it does do the job in a pinch.

Answer (score 0):

1. *Do not* hack the core (change any of the files in the initial Drupal download) unless you are using a patch in the issues queue or making one for a registered issue, `/includes` is part of that core.

The reason for this is that you will not be able to reliably upgrade your Drupal site as new versions are released and it is very important to keep it updated for security reasons.

2. *Do* always test new things on a development copy of your site, never on your production site (at least not after launch).

That being said, the best part of the answer you referenced is:

> All in all, I would prefer to just switch my MySQL to utf8mb4 charset, that supports all utf8 as it ought to be supported. You need MySQL 5.5.3 or greater to do this.

To elaborate:

MySQL allows various different encodings in its storage engine.  Latin1 (often the default) stores all of the data in one way and allows a limited set of characters.  UTF8 is a much larger library of characters.  Characters that exist in UTF8 that don't exist in Latin1 (for example) will make your database cry because it doesn't know how to read them.

The solution is to tell your database to use UTF8 instead of Latin1.

There are [instructions](http://www.varesano.net/blog/fabio/latin1%20encoded%20tables%20or%20databases%20utf8%20data%20stored%20convert%20them%20native%20mysql%20utf8%20tables) online for doing this in-place but I personally prefer to do a mysqldump and import the database into a fresh database that has been specifically set to use UTF8, then tell Drupal where to find the new database.

As Molot said in his answer, you need MySQL 5.5.3 or higher to use UTF8, so you may need to [upgrade your version of MySQL](https://www.google.com.au/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=upgrade%20mysql%20version).  If you're on shared hosting this could be difficult, you should be able to see your MySQL version in CPanel or Plesk, otherwise ask your hosting provider for support.

Comment: Thank you for your response, and I agree I do not wish to break the core. However the instructions he offered didn't quite make sense to me. Would you be able to elaborate a little but on them to possibly educate me on my disconnect?

Comment: Sure, updating answer.

Comment: That's a wonderful explanation Darvanen. Thank you for filling in the gap in my understanding. I spend most my time on the front end of things so this really helps me. I'll run through your linked suggestions to confirm and come back should this not fix my issue. Thank you very much.

Comment: Hi Darvanen, I was able to look into the options you'd provided, however, the problem still persists. The current website is setup with Server version 5.5.15 and UTF-8 Unicode (Utf8). 

Is there possibly anything else that would cause the emoji to error out the form? I've tested through acute e's and other special characters with no issue thus far. 

Thanks again for all your aid in better understanding this issue.

Comment: There is more than one type of utf8, [here's an explanation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-unicode-utf8mb4.html) of the difference between -general and -mb4.  Might still be the encoding.  Sorry I didn't point that out earlier.

Comment: Oh, not to worry on that part. That much I was aware of. and I tried resolving it with mb4 as well with no luck. My next step is to confirm the database fields are are all VARCHAR rather than TEXT types. In the event that doesn't resolve my issue, would you happen to have any other suggestions. 

Thanks again for your continued brainstorming in resolving this issue.

Comment: Did you try upgrading MySQL?  5.5.15 is quite out of date (and below the 5.5.3 mentioned by Molot).  Perhaps try 5.6?  It works fine with Drupal.

Comment: Sorry for the lengthy delay between posts on this one. Some other items came up that needed a bit more immediate attention. Server version is currently set to 5.5.40 MySQL Community Server (GPL). Server Charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8), and Server connection collation utf8mb4_general_ci.

The issue currently persists as it stands. By chance would the charset utf-8 unicode need to be reflected as mb4 as well? I'm unsure of anywhere else in webform to update?

Comment: That's the only thing I can think of (making sure table collation is utf8-mb4).

Comment: Thanks again for all your feedback Darvanen. I always appreciate a good brain storm.